# Infinite fraction's derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continued-fractions

> $f(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x+\dfrac{1}{x+\dfrac{1}{x+\ldots}}}$
>
> $f'\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=?$

I tried to make equation like $y^2=xy+1$ but I can't made it clearly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think $y^2=xy+1$ might be better.  You can solve $y^2-xy-1=0$ as a quadratic for $y$ in terms of $x$ and choose the sensible root, then differentiate and so find the derivative when $x=\frac32$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

For $ x\in [1,2]$, $ f(x)>0 $ and

$$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{f(x)} \implies$$

$$(f(x))^2-xf(x)-1=0\implies$$

$$f(x)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\implies$$
(take only the positive root of the quadratic)

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$$

You will find that
$$f\left(\frac 32\right)=2\;\text{ and }\; f'\left(\frac 32\right)=\frac 45$$

**Addendum :**

Other expressions for $\;f’(x)\;$ are the following ones :

$f’(x)=\dfrac{f^2(x)}{f^2(x)+1}$

$f’(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{2f(x)-x}$

Comment: Yes.  You have correctly ignored the possibility of  $f(x)=\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$ though without mentioning it or justifying it ($f(x)$ needs to be positive for positive $x$)

Comment: @Henry Yes you are right, i added the fact that $ f(x)>0 $ for $ x$ near 3/2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using implicit differentiation,
$f^2-xf-1=0
$
gives
$0
=2ff'-f-xf'
=(2f-x)f'-f
$
so
$f'
=\dfrac{f}{2f-x}
$.

Since
$f(x)
=\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}
$
(need the positive root),
$f(\frac32)
=\dfrac{\frac32+\sqrt{\frac94+4}}{2}
=\dfrac{\frac32+\sqrt{\frac{25}{4}}}{2}
=\dfrac{\frac32+\frac52}{2}
=2
$
so
$f'(\frac32)
=\dfrac{2}{4-\frac32}
=\frac45
$.